# Html canvas draw smooth lines with bezier curve

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a problem with my canvas lines is that whenever I try to draw lines they're not smooth, the lines look like a bunch of small lines connected with each other, I tried to find a solution using quadraticCurveTo and calculating a midpoint for the line

```js
const draw = (e) => {
    if (!isPainting) {
        return;
    }
    const x = e.pageX - canvasOffsetX;
    const y = e.pageY - canvasOffsetY;
    points.push({ x: x, y: y });
    ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.globalAlpha = opacity;
    ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = "high";
    ctx.beginPath();

    if (points.length === 1) {
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    } else {
        for (let i = 1, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
            let xc = (points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) / 2;
            let yc = (points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) / 2;
            ctx.quadraticCurveTo(points[i].x, points[i].y, xc, yc);

        }

        ctx.stroke();

    }
};
```

this method worked well but the lines appear after the mouse is up or after the calculation is done which isn't the best approach, I tried to draw the line before changing it after the mouse is up but it didn't work too

the only relative answer I was able to find was this codepen:
https://codepen.io/kangax/pen/kyYrdX

but the issue with it is that I have to clear the canvas before drawing new lines and I want all the drawings to be present

Answer (score 1):

It might be too late, but here is the solution by editing the codepen you mentioned.

1. You need to take a snapshot of the canvas on mousedown event and
   save it to a global variable
2. After you clear the canvas you need to paste that snapshot onto the
   canvas

```js
function midPointBtw(p1, p2) {
  return {
    x: p1.x + (p2.x - p1.x) / 2,
    y: p1.y + (p2.y - p1.y) / 2
  };
}

var el = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

var isDrawing, points = [ ];
var snapshot;
el.onmousedown = function(e) {
 snapshot = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, el.width, el.height);

  isDrawing = true;
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });
};

el.onmousemove = function(e) {
  if (!isDrawing) return;
  
  points.push({ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY });

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
   ctx.putImageData(snapshot, 0, 0);
  var p1 = points[0];
  var p2 = points[1];
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  console.log(points);

  for (var i = 1, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
    // we pick the point between pi+1 & pi+2 as the
    // end point and p1 as our control point
    var midPoint = midPointBtw(p1, p2);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(p1.x, p1.y, midPoint.x, midPoint.y);
    p1 = points[i];
    p2 = points[i+1];
  }
  // Draw last line as a straight line while
  // we wait for the next point to be able to calculate
  // the bezier control point
  ctx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.stroke();
};

el.onmouseup = function() {
  isDrawing = false;
  points.length = 0;
};
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid #ccc }
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```